# How to truncate a floating point number to an arbitrary decimal place?

Tags: number, floating-point

Are there packages that provide a command that can truncate a floating point number not to the nearest integer, but to an arbitrary decimal place? For instance, 2.59 truncated to the first decimal place is 2.5 (whereas *rounded* to the first decimal place, it is 2.6), and pi truncated to the third decimal place is 3.141 (whereas *rounded* to the third decimal place, it is 3.142).

Comment: `\fpeval{trunc(#1,1)}` from the [`xfp`](https://ctan.org/pkg/xfp) package (nowadays comes with LaTeX w/o having to load the package). Or `int(#1*10)/10` with PGFMath for example (or any other mathematical engine). Otherwise, `siunitx` can help with just printing these numbers.

Comment: Do you want to _print_ the value or to do further mathematics with it?

Comment: @JosephWright Print.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel I don't think `siunitx` can truncate to an arbitrary decimal place. It can round to an arbitrary decimal place, but not truncate. And the same applies to `pgfmath`.

Comment: You can combine siunitx and xfp (or just xfp if you don't need the pretty printer of siunitx). Pgfmath can with just the int function (but doesn't have the precision for it without additional library). Int is all you need, even for arbitrary decimal places.

Comment: @EvanAad Truncation would be easy to add to `siunitx`, but I'm wondering what the reason you want this is

Comment: @JosephWright The same reasons one would want to truncate to the nearest integer, and the same reasons one would want to round to an arbitrary number of decimal places. `siunitx` provides commands for both these purposes.

Comment: @JosephWright To give you a concrete example: suppose I want to print the first 4 digits in the infinite decimal expansion of pi: 3.14159...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Without packages, but you need a recent LaTeX release (from October 2021).

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\truncate}[2]{\fpeval{trunc(#1,#2)}}

\begin{document}

\truncate{pi}{0}

\truncate{pi}{2}

\truncate{exp(1)}{3}

\truncate{exp(sqrt(2))}{3}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Without packages.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\truncate[2]{\truncrep{#1}#2\relax}
\def\truncrep#1#2.#3#4\relax{%
  \ifx\relax#2\relax\else#2.\fi
  \ifnum#1>0 #3\expandafter\truncrep\expandafter
    {\the\numexpr#1-1}.#40\relax\fi
}
\begin{document}
\truncate{0}{10.347}

\truncate{1}{10.347}

\truncate{2}{10.347}

\truncate{3}{10.347}

\truncate{4}{10.347}

\truncate{5}{10.347}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Here's a LuaLaTeX-based solution. It requires no external packages.

The LaTeX macro `\truncate` takes two arguments.

- The first argument should be either a number or evaluate to a number, possibly with a decimal component, according to Lua's syntax rules.
- The second argument should be an integer.

  - If this integer equals 0, the pure integer part of the first argument (*without* the decimal marker) is returned
  - Otherwise, the first argument is truncated to the prescribed number of digits. The second argument may be negative; e.g., `\truncate{150,-2}` returns `100`.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\directlua{ % define a Lua function that does most of the work
```

```lua
   function xtrunc ( s , numdigits )
      if numdigits == 0 then
         return ( math.floor ( s ) )
      else
         s = math.floor ( s*10^numdigits ) / 10^numdigits 
         if numdigits>0 then 
            return s
         else 
            return math.floor ( s ) % remove decimal marker
         end
      end
   end
```

```tex
}
\newcommand\truncate[2]{\directlua{ 
   if #1 >= 0 then tex.sprint (  xtrunc (   #1  , #2 ) )
   else            tex.sprint ( -xtrunc ( -(#1) , #2 ) )
   end
}}
    
\begin{document}
\truncate{math.pi}{2}, 
\truncate{math.exp(1)}{5}, 
\truncate{1.73205}{1},
\truncate{1.73205}{0}
\end{document}
```

Comment: given the use of `math.floor()`, isn't the first argument also required to be non-negative?

Comment: @BenVoigt - Good question! My working assumption was, possibly without justification, that the first argument would be a positive number. I've gone ahead and augmented the code to handle the case of the first argument being a negative number. Thanks for pointing out this potential issue.

Comment: I think it was perfectly fine to handle only non-negative inputs.  But you went to the trouble of explicitly listing a non-negativity constraint on the second parameter, so I thought such a constraint on the first parameter should be made explicit too (or removed as you did)

Comment: @BenVoigt - I've noticed that the second argument does *not* have to be non-negative (although it should be an integer, as otherwise the exercise doesn't make sense to begin with). E.g., `\truncate{1515.1515}{-2}` evaluates to `1500`, i.e., the nearest smaller multiple of `100=10^2`.  I've updated the write-up to remove this restriction.